# jQuery error after setting anchor tag dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set the href property of an anchor tag using jquery, by writing this code:

```
 myPage.URL != null ? $pages.find("#myPage").attr("href", myPage.URL.Url) : $pages.find("#myPage").attr("href", "#") ;
```

Where myPage object contains an object called URL 2 properties: Url and Description. If URL is not null, then for sure it will have a Url value.

After running this code, I try to click on the link, but it's giving this error:

> jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://yourlink.com(…)

Here's `myPage` object structure:

```
 pageType : "publishing",
 pageCategory: null 
 Steps : null
 pageOwner: null 
 audience: "All"
 audienceDescription: "description goes here for the audience"
 Title : "my page title"
 URL : Object
    > Description "any link goes here" 
    > Url "http://google.com"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: If the error is shown *after* you click the link then we need to see the code of the click event handler.

Comment: Share with us the `myPage` object structure.

Comment: Why not simplify it with: $pages.find("#myPage").attr("href", myPage.URL != null ? myPage.URL.Url, "#"); That shouldn't solve the problem (which I assume has to do with the value of myPage.URL.Url) but will simplify the code.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I updated the snippet to show the object structure

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, it's just an anchor element on the page `<a>` , I expected it to have the url for the new href value am setting. there's no custom event handler

Comment: `$pages.find("#myPage").attr("href", myPage.URL.Url || "#");` much shorter version.

Comment: Your code should work @Jacky https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/257/ (at least the posted here)

Comment: @Jai, won't it give an error if you tried to access Url if the URL is null .. ?

Comment: what is $pages?? is it the document if so then it works

Comment: SOunds like your object has a syntax error

Comment: @MugiwaraUK, $pages is actually $("#pagesContainer"). I am using to find my elements

Comment: @Jacky then in that case it would set #.

Comment: What does the actual object look like that you are reading the data from? When you click on the error message in the console, where does it take you?

Comment: @Jai no, it didn't, it said: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Url' of null`

Comment: @Jai, you're access the Url directly without checking if the parent is null or not .. so it won't work

Comment: @epascarello, it doesn't take my anywhere, it just stays on the page with the error showing in the console.

Comment: @Jacky, inspect the link element using the browser Inspector and check if the url was properly set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need also to check if your object `myPage.URL` has the property `Url` then assign it :

```
if( myPage.URL != null )
     if( myPage.URL.hasOwnProperty("Url") )
           $pages.find("#myPage").attr("href", myPage.URL.Url);
     else
           $pages.find("#myPage").attr("href", "#")
```

Hope this helps.